# Is it possible to find out who created a tag or a branch in CVS?

Tags: version-control, cvs

Commits obviously have an author associated with them; but is it possible to find out which user created a tag or a branch on a CVS repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have history enabled (which I think is the default) and your tag was created using `cvs rtag` then you can use:

```
cvs history -a -T
```

If you want tags that are created from within the branch via `cvs tag` then you are out of luck as the history command [does not support that](http://cvsbook.red-bean.com/cvsbook.html#History%20--%20A%20Summary%20Of%20Repository%20Activity).

One thing to bear in mind is that in CVS tags are not repository-wide. They apply at the file level. So it is entirely possible for different people to apply the same tag to different files at different times.